# when BinaryFileResponse is used file checksum changes

Tags: php, file, symfony

I used BinaryFileResponse class to create download file response. file is a zip file.
file checksum is different after file being downloaded.
why this happens and can we send the original file as response.

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
$response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $fileName
);

return $response->send();
```

Comment: If you are in a controller, '->send()' is not needed. Only return '$response'

Comment: actually that solved my problem. thanks @silvioq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a controller, `->send()` is not needed ...

Your code should  be ...

```
<?php

class MyController 
{
    public function action()
    {
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        $response->setContentDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            $fileName
        );

        return $response;
    }
}
```